# Angular 4 - Route with children doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Hi I have the following routes structure:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'site', component: MainViewComponent, pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'extra-details', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'extra-details', component: ExtraDetailsViewComponent}    
  ]},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginViewComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

both login and 404 (Page not found) are working great, the thing is that when I try to access /site it is being redirected to /site/extra-details but it displays the 404 view. When I commented the '**' path I got the following error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'site/extra-details'

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Matan

Comment: `pathMatch` is required only when you are redirecting, remove it where you have defined component.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan That really was the problem, can't belive that was the issue. I would have expect to at least get a warning by angular when using both `pathMatch` and `component`.

Comment: Glad to know that it resolved, I have added it as an answer please accept and upvote, Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pathMatch` is required only when you are redirecting, remove it where you have defined component.

Comment: You may need `pathMatch` with components in different situations.